# jquery Isotope Sort Exception on Filter Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filtering, jquery-isotope

I have isotope working as a product sorting matrix using checkbox combo filters (styled with jquery UI), groups and hash history.  All in all, everything is working as expected and the result has turned out very nice.  I have run into an issue where I need to re-sort the filter results based on certain checkboxes.  If you look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwbennet/B8kV3/2/ you can see my results.  The issue is, if you scroll down to the checkboxes and choose "Wellness Incentives" I need all "Mastercard" tagged results to come first in the results.  So as a basic sort, everything is just alphabetical and if you choose some checkboxes the results just remain alphabetical, but if you choose "Wellness Incentives" as one of the "Uses", the results should re-sort and start with the "Mastercard" results.  There are other exceptions, but this is just one example.  Is there a way to do what I am explaining here built into Isotope?  Thank you very much in advance for any consideration given to this issue.

Currently, here is my Isotope code:

```
 var $container = $('#container');
 var $filterDisplay = $('#filter-display');

 // Initiate Isotope and pass in hash change filter
 $container.isotope({
    filter: hashfilter
 });

 if( location.hash != "" ){
   var hashfilter = location.hash.substr( 1 );
 } else {
   var hashfilter = "*";
 }

 var filters = {};

 isOptionLinkClicked = false;

 $('#options').on( 'change', function( jQEvent ) {

   var checkbox = jQEvent.target;
   var $checkbox = $( checkbox );
   var value = checkbox.value;
   var group = $checkbox.parents('.option-set').attr('data-group');

   // create array for filter group, if not there yet
   if ( !filters[ group ] ) {
     filters[ group ] = [];
   }

var index = $.inArray( checkbox.value, filters[ group ] );

if ( checkbox.checked ) {
  var selector = 'input';
  $checkbox.siblings( selector ).removeAttr('checked');


  if ( index === -1 ) {
    // add filter to group
    filters[ group ].push( checkbox.value );
    isOptionLinkClicked = true;
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    //console.log($(this).data());
  }

  } else {
    // remove filter from group
    filters[ group ].splice( index, 1 );

  }


   var i = 0;
   var comboFilters = [];

  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];

    // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
    if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
      continue;
    }

    if ( i === 0 ) {
      // copy to new array
      comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);

    } else {

    var filterSelectors = [];

    // copy to fresh array
    var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // ex: [ A, B ]

    // merge filter Groups
    for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {

      for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
        filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
      }

    }

    // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
    comboFilters = filterSelectors
  }
  i++

  location.hash = comboFilters.join(', ');

  var hashObject = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );

  //return false;
}

$container.isotope({ filter: comboFilters.join(', ') });

// Helpful for messing with hashchange URLs
//$filterDisplay.text( comboFilters.join(', ') );

});

var hashObject = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
var hashChanged = false;

$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ){

if(location.hash != "") {
    var hashfilter = location.hash.substr(1);
} else {
    var hashfilter = "*";
}

$container.isotope({
    filter: hashfilter
});

})

// trigger hashchange to capture initial hash options
.trigger( 'hashchange' );

// trigger ui clicks to mirror initial hash options
var strHash = location.hash.substr(1); // Get our url hash
var arHash = strHash.split(" ").join("").split(",").join("").split("."); 
// get rid of the spaces, commas, and conver to an array
var arHashUnique = Array(); // remove duplicates from the array
$.each(arHash, function(i, item){
   if($.inArray(item, arHashUnique) === -1 && item != "") 
   {
      arHashUnique.push(item);
   }
});

for(var i in arHashUnique) // click the appropriate filters {
  $("#" + arHashUnique[i]).click();
}
```

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html